# iOS : How to reload a UITableView with a lot of cells without lagging the App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a lot of cells (around 3000 cells) that I need to reload constantly. I was wondering if there is currently a way to reload it faster without it lagging the App. I do the typical `[tableview reloadData];` Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: odd that you are getting a lag. What is you table view doing.

Comment: have you used a custom height for every cell ?

Comment: do you need to reload the whole table view at once? If not, why don't you use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` (or insert / delete rows)? Some sample code showing what you do with the table view could be useful.

Comment: Provide more details. Update your question with relevant code used for reloading the table. And what kind of lag are you seeing?

Comment: Are you re-using your `UITableViewCell`'s?

Comment: Do you have images in your cells? This can cause significant lag. UITableView only loads visible cells, so the size of the table doesn't matter. If you are using Core Data I suggest using NSFetchedResultsController. If not, try updating only the cells that are changing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't implement tableView:heightForRow: in your delegate or it will slow down considerably as it recalculates every row.  iOS checks to see if you implement that method and if you define it the OS changes its table height calculation from a simple multiply to a loop over the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided context or code to show where you call `[tableview reloadData];`, I can only talk in generalities.

I am going to assume in your 3,000 rows possible 20 are displayed at a time.

Here is the sequence of events or actions that needs to occurs

- A row gets update
- Check if row is visible: `indexPathForVisibleRows`
- If row is not visible, nothing to do

If row is visible, then following actions should be taken

- `[tableview beginUpdates]`
- `[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths...]`
- `[tableview endUpdates]`

Answer (score 0):

Reload only visible cells if you have consistent number of items, otherwise use insert/delete methods to add cells to tableview.

Answer (score 0):

When making a reloadData for your tableView, tableView:heightForRow: delegate function make a height recalculation of every row.

My solution is to save the heights for your cells already calculated (create an NSDictionary that contains all row heights. exp. create a NSDictionary with keys is the id of object that will be show on the cell and the value is the height).

When tableView attempt to recalculate the height of each cell, it will check if we have already a saved entry in your dictionary with this key (id of object), and tableView:heightForRow: will return this value if found.
I am using this solution in my chat app, and I noticed a performance increase.
Good luck.